# How to compare a "basic_string" using an arbitary locale

Tags: c++

I'm re-posting a question I submitted earlier today but I'm now citing a specific example in response to the feedback I received. The original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269449/why-are-basic-string-and-locale-so-difficult-to-use-in-c) (note that it's not a homework assignment):

I'm simply trying to determine if C++ makes it impossible to perform an (efficient) **case-INsensitive** comparison of a `basic_string` object that also factors in any arbitrary `locale` object. For instance, it doesn't appear to be possible to write an efficient function such as the following:

```
bool AreStringsEqualIgnoreCase(const string &str1, const string &str2, const locale &loc);
```

Based on my current understanding (but can someone confirm this), this function *has* to call both `ctype::toupper()` and `collate::compare()` for the given `locale` (extracted as always using `use_facet()`). However, because `collate::compare()` in particular requires 4 pointer args, you either need to pass these 4 args for every char you need to compare (after first calling `ctype::toupper()`), or alternatively, convert both strings to upppercase first and then make a single call to `collate::compare()`.

The 1st approach is obviously inefficient (4 pointers to pass for each char tested), and the 2nd requires you to convert both strings to uppercase in their entirety (requiring allocation of memory and needless copying/converting of both strings to uppercase). Am I correct about this, i.e.,  it's not possible to do it efficiently (because there's no way around `collate::compare()`).

Comment: I see you're still into posting gigantic walls of text.

Comment: Here's [the help for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). A link to it was provided as you wrote your question, so you've seen it and ignored it twice today. Perhaps now's the time to take a look, yes?

Comment: I improved the formatting of this current post, but you should really learn how to do it for future questions.

Comment: A cursory read of [`collate::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/collate/compare) tells me you might be misunderstanding its parameters. In particular, you do *not* need to "pass 4 args for every char". Its arguments are simply two strings, each with a pointer to its start and its end (as an alternative to 0-terminated strings or supplying a length).

Comment: @Lightness: Your comments are noted.

Comment: @Lightness: It takes 4 pointers. If you're doing this one char at a time, args 2 and 4 would point to one past the (single) char you're comparing in each of the two strings. It needs to iterate until this is found, and this has to be set up for every character, but there's only 1 character on each call. It also relies on a virtual function ("do_compare()" as per the standard), there's no guarantee it will be inlined, etc. It's inherently slow so where's the misunderstanding?

Comment: both case sensitive and insensitive string compares are O(n). I'm wondering what your use case looks like that expanding the stack with a couple upper case strings is deal-breaking.

Comment: @Red: No particular stats. I'm updating a string library to be "locale" sensitive and trying to get a handle on things. Based on what I cited, it appears to be a serious performance issue, with no way around it if I understand the situation.

Comment: There's no "guarantee" that anything ever will be inlined.

Comment: @Lightness: Agreed, which is exactly my point. In addition to the other inefficiencies, each call to "collate::compare()" (potentially) involves pushing 4 pointers onto the stack and this occurs for every character compared (not good).

Comment: I don't find it useful to make a "point" that has no intrinsic relevance to this question. It's like saying "there's no guarantee that my C++ compiler can compile PHP, that's my point" which has nothing to do with the topic at hand. When you said "there's no guarantee it will be inlined" before, the implication was that you had some alternative in mind which does hold such a guarantee, but no such entity exists in C++.

Comment: @Lightness: Ok, I'll take the blame for the misunderstanding but room for comments are short or I would have elaborated. The problem still exists however and I don't see anyway to circumvent it (there appears to be none).

Comment: There is no problem...

Comment: @Lightness: Then the blame for misunderstanding shifts back to you.

Comment: Ironclad argument, there; I enjoyed it greatly. Oh well, _you know best_, then.

Comment: @Lightness: The irony is enough to choke on considering you've said nothing to correct me. I'd be happy to hear it but I guess *you* know best though. Never mind, "there is no problem" so now I understand (thanks for your insight).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One of the little annoyances about trying to deal in a consistent way with all the world's writing systems is that practically nothing you think you know about characters is actually correct. This makes it tricky to do things like "case-insensitive comparison". Indeed, it is tricky to do any form of locale-aware comparison, and case-insensitivity is additionally thorny.

With some constraints, though, it is possible to accomplish. The algorithm needed can be implemented "efficiently" using normal programming practices (and precomputation of some static data), but it cannot be implemented as efficiently as an incorrect algorithm. It is often possible to trade off correctness for speed, but the results are not pleasant. Incorrect but fast locale implementations may appeal to those whose locales are implemented correctly, but are clearly unsatisfactory for the part of the audience whose locales produce unexpected results.

**Lexicographical ordering doesn't work for human beings**

Most locales (other than the "C" locale) for languages which have case already handle letter case in the manner expected, which is to use case differences only after all other differences have been taken into account. That is, if a list of words are sorted in the locale's collation order, then words in the list which differ only in case are going to be consecutive. Whether the words with upper case come before or after words with lower case is locale-dependent, but there won't be other words in between.

That result cannot be achieved by any single-pass left-to-right character-by-character comparison ("lexicographical ordering"). And most locales have other collation quirks which also don't yield to naïve lexicographical ordering.

Standard C++ collation should be able to deal with all of these issues, if you have appropriate locale definitions. But it cannot be reduced to lexicographical comparison just using a comparison function over pairs of `whar_t`, and consequently the C++ standard library doesn't provide that interface.

The following is just a few examples of why locale-aware collation is complicated; a longer explanation, with a lot more examples, is found in [Unicode Technical Standard 10](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

**Where do the accents go?**

Most romance languages (and also English, when dealing with borrowed words) consider accents over vowels to be a *secondary characteristic*; that is, words are first sorted as though the accents weren't present, and then a second pass is made in which unaccented letters come before accented letters. A third pass is necessary to deal with case, which is ignored in the first two passes.

But that doesn't work for Northern European languages. The alphabets of Swedish, Norwegian and Danish have three extra vowels, which follow <kbd>z</kbd> in the alphabet. In Swedish, these vowels are written <kbd>å</kbd>, <kbd>ä</kbd>, and <kbd>ö</kbd>; in Norwegian and Danish, these letters are written <kbd>å</kbd>, <kbd>æ</kbd>, and <kbd>ø</kbd>, and in Danish <kbd>å</kbd> is sometimes written <kbd>aa</kbd>, making Aarhus the last entry in an alphabetical list of Danish cities.

In German, the letters <kbd>ä</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, and <kbd>ü</kbd> are generally alphabetised as with romance accents, but in German phonebooks (and sometimes other alphabetical lists), they are alphabetised as though they were written <kbd>ae</kbd>, <kbd>oe</kbd> and <kbd>ue</kbd>, which is the older style of writing the same phonemes. (There are many pairs of common surnames such as "Müller" and "Mueller" are pronounced the same and are often confused, so it makes sense to intercollate them. A similar convention was used for Scottish names in Canadian phonebooks when I was young; the spellings `M'`, `Mc` and `Mac` were all clumped together since they are all phonetically identical.)

**One symbol, two letters. Or two letters, one symbol**

German also has the symbol <kbd>ß</kbd> which is collated as though it were written out as <kbd>ss</kbd>, although it is not quite identical phonetically. We'll meet this interesting symbol again a bit later.

In fact, many languages consider digraphs and even trigraphs to be single letters. The 44-letter Hungarian alphabet includes <kbd>Cs</kbd>, <kbd>Dz</kbd>, <kbd>Dzs</kbd>, <kbd>Gy</kbd>, <kbd>Ly</kbd>, <kbd>Ny</kbd>, <kbd>Sz</kbd>, <kbd>Ty</kbd>, and <kbd>Zs</kbd>, as well as a variety of accented vowels. However, the language most commonly referenced in articles about this phenomenon -- Spanish -- stopped treating the digraphs <kbd>ch</kbd> and <kbd>ll</kbd> as letters in 1994, presumably because it was easier to force Hispanic writers to conform to computer systems than to change the computer systems to deal with Spanish digraphs. (Wikipedia claims it was pressure from "UNESCO and other international organizations"; it took quite a while for everyone to accept the new alphabetization rules, and you still occasionally find "Chile" after "Colombia" in alphabetical lists of South American countries.)

**Summary: comparing character strings requires multiple passes, and sometimes requires comparing groups of characters**

**Making it all case-insensitive**

Since locales handle case correctly in comparison, it should not really be necessary to do case-insensitive ordering. It might be useful to do case-insensitive equivalence-class checking ("equality" testing), although that raises the question of what other imprecise equivalence classes might be useful. Unicode normalization, accent deletion, and even transcription to latin are all reasonable in some contexts, and highly annoying in others. But it turns out that case conversions are not as simple as you might think, either.

Because of the existence of di- and trigraphs, some of which have Unicode codepoints, the Unicode standard actually recognizes three cases, not two: lower-case, upper-case and title-case. The last is what you use to upper case the first letter of a word, and it's needed, for example, for the Croatian digraph <kbd>ǆ</kbd> (U+01C6; a single character), whose uppercase is <kbd>Ǆ</kbd> (U+01C4) and whose title case is <kbd>ǅ</kbd> (U+01C5). The theory of "case-insensitive" comparison is that we could transform (at least conceptually) any string in such a way that all members of the equivalence class defined by "ignoring case" are transformed to the same byte sequence. Traditionally this is done by "upper-casing" the string, but it turns out that that is not always possible or even correct; the Unicode standard prefers the use of the term "case-folding", as do I.

**C++ locales aren't quite up to the job**

So, getting back to C++, the sad truth is that C++ locales do not have sufficient information to do accurate case-folding, because C++ locales work on the assumption that case-folding a string consists of nothing more than sequentially and individually upper-casing each codepoint in the string using a function which maps a codepoint to another codepoint. As we'll see, that just doesn't work, and consequently the question of its efficiency is irrelevant. On the other hand, the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) has an interface which does case-folding as correctly as the Unicode database allows, and its implementation has been crafted by some pretty good coders so it is probably just about as efficient as possible within the constraints. So I'd definitely recommend using it.

If you want a good overview of the difficulty of case-folding, you should read sections 5.18 and 5.19 of the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/) ([PDF for chapter 5](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch05.pdf)). The following is just a few examples.

**A case transform is not a mapping from single character to single character**

The simplest example is the German <kbd>ß</kbd> (U+00DF), which has no upper-case form because it never appears at the beginning of a word, and traditional German orthography didn't use all-caps. The standard upper-case transform is <kbd>SS</kbd> (or in some cases <kbd>SZ</kbd>) but that transform is not reversible; not all instances of <kbd>ss</kbd> are written as <kbd>ß</kbd>. Compare, for example, grüßen and küssen (to greet and to kiss, respectively). In v5.1, ẞ, an "upper-case ß, was added to Unicode as U+1E9E, but it is not commonly used except in all-caps street signs, where its use is legally mandated. The normal expectation of upper-casing ß would be the two letters `SS`.

**Not all ideographs (visible characters) are single character codes**

Even when a case transform maps a single character to a single character, it may not be able to express that as a `wchar→wchar` mapping. For example, <kbd>ǰ</kbd> can easily be capitalized to <kbd>J̌</kbd>, but the former is a single combined glyph (U+01F0), while the second is a capital J with a combining caron (U+030C).

There is a further problem with glyphs like <kbd>ǰ</kbd>:

**Naive character by character case-folding can denormalize**

Suppose we upper-case <kbd>ǰ</kbd> as above. How do we capitalize <kbd>ǰ̠</kbd> (which, in case it doesn't render properly on your system, is the same character with an bar underneath, another IPA convention)? That combination is U+01F0,U+0320 (j with caron, combining minus sign below), so we proceed to replace U+01F0 with U+004A,U+030C and then leave the U+0320 as is: <kbd>J̠̌</kbd>. That's fine, but it won't compare equal to a normalized capital J with caron and minus sign below, because in the normal form the minus sign diacritic comes first: U+004A,U+0320,U+030C (<kbd>J̠̌</kbd>, which should look identical). So sometimes (rarely, to be honest, but sometimes) it is necessary to renormalize.

**Leaving aside unicode wierdness, sometimes case-conversion is context-sensitive**

Greek has a lot of examples of how marks get shuffled around depending on whether they are word-initial, word-final or word-interior -- you can read more about this in chapter 7 of the Unicode standard -- but a simple and common case is <kbd>Σ</kbd>, which has two lower-case versions: <kbd>σ</kbd> and <kbd>ς</kbd>. Non-greeks with some maths background are probably familiar with <kbd>σ</kbd>, but might not be aware that it cannot be used at the end of a word, where you must use <kbd>ς</kbd>.

**In short**

1. The best available correct way to case-fold is to apply the Unicode case-folding algorithm, which requires creating a temporary string for each source string. You could then do a simple bytewise comparison between the two transformed strings in order to verify that the original strings were in the same equivalence class. Doing a collation ordering on the transformed strings, while possible, is rather less efficient than collation ordering the original strings, and for sorting purposes, the untransformed comparison is probably as good or better than the transformed comparison.
2. In theory, if you are only interested in case-folded equality, you could do the transformations linearly, bearing in mind that the transformation is not necessarily context-free and is not a simple character-to-character mapping function. Unfortunately, C++ locales don't provide you the data you need to do this. The Unicode CLDR comes much closer, but it's a complex datastructure.
3. All of this stuff is really complicated, and rife with edge cases. (See the note in the Unicode standard about accented Lithuanian `i`'s, for example.) You're really better off just using a well-maintained existing solution, of which the best example is ICU.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (it is appreciated) and I'll consider what you said. However, to be perfectly honest, it doesn't actually address my question. The issue I'm dealing with is a purely technical limitation of the standard library, namely, that you have to call "collate::compare()" and doing so is inefficient. Whether converting to uppercase and then relying on the latter function is 100% accurate is a completely separate issue. Relying on 3rd-party libraries isn't always a viable option, and simply not necessary for many apps. Converting to uppercase and comparing is often good enough.

Comment: @MikeR: If you agree that converting to uppercase cannot, in general, be done by iterating a wchar_t->wchar_t mapping function, then the solution of uppercasing (or, better, case-folding) the entire string to a temporary buffer becomes quite reasonable. In a resource-constrained environment (if that's your issue), recycling temporary buffers can significantly reduce overhead.

Comment: Well that may be the answer right there. If there really is no choice but to convert the entire string to uppercase first then problem solved. Part of my confusion however stems from this link (http://lafstern.org/matt/col2_new.pdf). The author should know what he's doing in theory (given his credentials) but have a quick look at his "lt_str_1" struct. It's character-based and moreover, the return statement inside the nested "lt_char" struct doesn't appear legit. He should be routing things through "collate::compare()". Do you agree that this solution isn't legitimate then?

Comment: @MikeR: OK, it's now a full-length essay. Hope you like it. As for the linked document, that was written in 2000. Hopefully the author has learned a lot more about localization since then. Despite his qualifications as a programmer, I don't see anything in his CV which would indicate that he is an expert in localization, and indeed the code in the example is not valid. I agree that "case-fold and byte-compare" is often good enough (although I personally prefer to case-fold and normalize), but it's still non-trivial and ICU does it better than  the C++ standard library.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Matt Austern was former chair of the C++ standardization committee's library working group so there was a cautious assumption he knew what he was doing. That it was 14 years ago is irrelevant really (the article is also cited by other high-placed people). In any case, I looked at ICU and found a boost wrapper for it though I didn't want to step outside the std library. The boost docs also have some solid info on the issues discussed so I'm on the right track now. I just need to consider how I want to proceed. Thanks again for your help. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW, I would up-vote your response but apparently I don't have sufficient rights yet (I'm new). I'll definitely cite it for others in the future though (very helpful).

Comment: Oh, and one last thing for anyone else reading this. Converting strings to uppercase first and then calling "collate::compare()" is faster on my compiler (VS2012) than converting each char individually and calling "collate::compare()" (as I figured). Your own compiler might differ of course (though I doubt it).

Comment: @MikeR: It's cool that it's faster, but it's more important that it is more accurate. For example, Try it in the Spanish locale with `regañadientes`, `régimen`, and `regular`, which should sort in that order. Any other order is not adequate for any application which cares about its Spanish-speaking users (of which I'm one, so I write with some self-interest). By the way, if you find the response useful, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark; that doesn't have a minimum rep afaik.

Comment: Ok, checkmarked (thanks for the tip). I do agree that getting these issues right is important but the cost also has to be considered. To do it "right" is just plain expensive, given all the issues involved. From dealing with surrogage pairs (in my world of UTF-16 Windows), to trying to work within the framework of native C++ locales (do I really want to pull in a 3rd-party lib like ICU), it's just plain hard, especially if code like Matt Austern's will in fact handle most cases within reason (in the real-world). It's a trade-off but only because doing it "right" can be prohibitvely expensive.

Comment: @MikeR: But Austern's code doesn't handle Spanish (or any other romance language such as French, Portuguese or Italian). Does that mean that only English speakers live in the "real world"? :) (In the case of romance accents, standard C++'s compare function works fine if you use it on the entire string. However, it might not work with Danish.)

Comment: In UTF-16 Windows, making his code "wchar_t" based instead of "char" (forgot to mention that - mea culpa) will result in acceptable behavior in a wide variety of applications. Calling "collate::compare()" would also be safer as discussed. All of this confined to the BMP of course. The alternative is to support multibyte encoding, 1:X case mappings, large and performance-degrading 3rd-party libraries (ICU), etc. It's expensive and error-prone and IMHO, if a plane isn't going to drop out of the sky, many apps can simply live without it (and do of course, warts and all). There's no free lunch :)

Comment: I should make it clear that I do in fact agree with you in principle though, it's only that in "real world" environments, it's not so simple. Dealing with issues like "basic_string::size()" no longer returning what you think it does (potentially) can result in a lot of problems (and that's just one of many issues).

Comment: Just as an FYI — U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S was present in Unicode 5.1 (possibly earlier) from 2008.

Comment: @jonathan: It was indeed added in v5.1, April 2008. I did write this answer some time ago, but perhaps "recently" was a bit dated even then.

Comment: It was pure fluke that I happened to have the first version of the PDF with that letter in it — I had no idea that it was added in v5.1; just that it was present in there.  I happened not to have a more recent version of the PDF file.

Comment: @jonathan: http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/ubrowse?go=1e9e. The value of the "derived age" attribute is the version in which the codepoint was assigned.