# Is it possible to make compact Unicode compatible strtoupper()/strtolower() functions in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, utf-32

I've been researching libraries for converting a Latin-1 compatible (using `unsigned char`) C application to be Unicode compatible.

[ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/home) seems to be the most promising, but it's also a huge library and hard to integrate/build (especially considering it needs to compile for iOS, Android, Windows, WASM and Linux).

I only really need fixed-length encoding and the ability to convert case - would it be possible to do this using only UTF-32 strings (stored as `int[]`) and two UTF-32 compatible `strtoupper()`/`strtolower()` functions or is there something preventing me from doing this (such as ligatures or combining characters)?

My plan was to make a static list of upper/lowercase mappings and use it as a lookup table (or rather, consolidate ranges of characters of the same "type" to save space).

Comment: Do you need to German `ß` to be replaced with `SS` when converted to uppercase? What about turkish `I` and `İ` (dotted I)? And how does Latin-1 is related to Unicode? A little bit unclear what you need.

Comment: @StaceyGirl remember having heard that there's a special Unicode for upper ß. No ideas about the turkish characters though

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I think it has been added (to the language, not just Unicode) a little less than 10 years ago, but I haven't seen it being used - all conversion functions I used always returned `SS`. So I am not sure what is the best conversion at the moment.

Comment: @stacey girl I know that's far more common .. boh ways of 'uppercasing' ß look somehow ugly to me

Comment: @StaceyGirl I think I'd need to see the cases where there are ambiguities and then make a decision based on that. If a static mapping is somehow possible I can always just set it up for whatever I want.

Comment: Side-note: Don't use arrays of `int`; [C11 introduced a proper type for this, `char32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char32_t). While it's likely your code will never run on a system with 16 bit ints, using `char32_t` will make your intent much more clear.

Comment: I've found a newspapar article from 2017 stating 'uppercase ß' is now official (in german of course: [https://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/eszett-jetzt-gibt-es-das-ss-auch-als-grossbuchstaben-a-1155053.html]

Comment: @StaceyGirl oh yeah I forgot, Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 is 8 bit and the first 256 characters of Unicode, but stored as a single byte (meaning `unsigned char` works).

Comment: @Woodgnome There are many unicode characters and defined rules for lower-casing and upper-casing. I suppose the question is, whether you want to be conforming or just want something working for the Latin alphabet. See https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html

Comment: @uneven_mark I need it working for characters outside Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 - Polish and Icelandic for example. Maybe Russian or Turkish in the long term.

Comment: @Woodgnome If you just need to do 1-to-1 conversion, I can recommend looking at musl implementation of [towupper](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/ctype/towctrans.c).

Comment: Here's my take on Unicode case-folding and why I think you should use ICU if you care about correctness: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281505/1566221. Not marked as dupe because I don't want to wield the hammer.

Comment: @rici I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, but if you  were to answer with a quote of your post from where you reference the Unicode standard 5.18/5.19 I would accept that as an answer, because it shows you *can* implement a usable function, but it will be with limitations in several languages (which you have highlighted).